# No Response from mysql database in POST data using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using nodejs and express to connect my local mysql db, everythings look working well except no response when Iam trying to test the API in postman.
here is my code in server.js

```
//add sales
app.post('/sales',(req, res) => {
  var POST_SALES_QUERY = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    fullname: req.body.fullname
  }
  if (!POST_SALES_QUERY) {
    return res.status(400).send({ err: true, message: 'Please username' });
  }
  dbConn.query("INSERT INTO user_tbl SET ?", (POST_SALES_QUERY, err, results) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "err" : null, "response": results}));
    }    
  });
});
```

and in Postman, I get this:
[image: API test result in postman]

any idea what the problem appears here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.post('/sales',(req, res) => {
  var POST_SALES_QUERY = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    fullname: req.body.fullname
  }
  if (!POST_SALES_QUERY) {
    return res.status(400).send({ err: true, message: 'Please username' });
  }

  let query = `INSERT INTO user_tbl (username, password, fullname) VALUES ('${POST_SALES_QUERY.username}','${POST_SALES_QUERY.password}','${POST_SALES_QUERY.fullname}')`;

  dbConn.query(query,function(err,results) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({"status": 200,"err": null,"response": results});
    }    
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell express to treat the body as json, by calling the following codes:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

As per [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html):

> This is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on body-parser.

Comment: thanks for your response ... I tried to add the codes, and I still get same response in my terminal like this:
``` code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlMessage: "Column 'username' cannot be null",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO user_tbl SET `username` = NULL, `password` = NULL, `fullname` = NULL'
```